# Format the string with missing elements - Python

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
string1 = "1/0/1/A1,A2"
string2 = "1/1/A1,A2"
string3 = "0/A1,A2"
```

In the above strings I have to replace the character with zero if it does not exist. The default structure will be "number/number/number/any_character`", if any of number is missing It has to replace with zero. The answer will be as follows.

```
print(string1) = "1/0/1/A1,A2"
print(string2) = "1/1/0/A1,A2"
print(string3) = "0/0/0/A1,A2"
```

Comment: how will the code know which element is missing.... that means in string3 = "0/A1,A2" are 0 and A1 the 3rd and 4th elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split`:

```
def pad_string(_input, _add='0'):
  *_vals, _str = _input.split('/')
  return '/'.join([*_vals, *([_add]*(3-len(_vals))), _str])

results = list(map(pad_string, ['1/0/1/A1,A2', '1/1/A1,A2', '0/A1,A2']))
```

Output:

```
['1/0/1/A1,A2', '1/1/0/A1,A2', '0/0/0/A1,A2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fill missing elements from the left:

```
def fillZeros(item):
    chunks = item.split('/')
    for inserts in range(0, 4 - len(chunks)):
        chunks.insert(0, '0')
    return '/'.join(chunks)

string1 = "1/0/1/A1,A2"
string2 = "1/1/A1,A2"
string3 = "0/A1,A2"


for myString in (string1, string2, string3):
    print fillZeros(myString)
```

Prints:

```
1/0/1/A1,A2
0/1/1/A1,A2
0/0/0/A1,A2
```

But for you `string2` example you need to identify which element is missing: `1/1/A1,A2`. Is the first or the third element missing ?!

Comment: Third element. It only validate suffix

Comment: Yes - how do you distinguish between suffix and prefix ?

Comment: Always we have to append to suffix.

Comment: Ajax1234's answer covers this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just string manipulation and loops, try this

```
strings_list = []
for string in [string1, string2, string3]:     # make list containing all strings
    strings_list.append(string)

new_strings = [] # make list containing the new strings
for string in strings_list:
    if string.count("0/") + string.count("1/") == 3:
        # identify the strings not missing a number
        new_strings.append(string)
    if string.count("0/") + string.count("1/") == 2:
        # identify the strings missing 1 number
        string = string[:4] + "0/" + string[4:]
        new_strings.append(string)
    if string.count("0/") + string.count("1/") == 1:
        # identify the strings missing 2 numbers
        string = string[:2] + "0/" + string[2:]
        new_strings.append(string)
print(new_strings)
```

This results in `['1/0/1/A1,A2', '1/1/0/A1,A2', '0/0/A1,A2']`.